# Python: catch either one of two exceptions

Tags: python, try-catch

I have the following piece of code. `article_as_dict` is a dictionary that I'm receiving from an external source:

```
final_dict["short_title"] = article_as_dict["short_title"]
try:
    final_dict["picture_url"] = article_as_dict["main_image"]["img"][-1]["link"]
except IndexError:
    final_dict["picture_url"] = None
```

I discovered recently that I also need to account for a possible `KeyError`, is the block below the most pythonic way to do this?

```
final_dict["short_title"] = article_as_dict["short_title"]
try:
    final_dict["picture_url"] = article_as_dict["main_image"]["img"][-1]["link"]
except IndexError:
    final_dict["picture_url"] = None
except KeyError:
    final_dict["picture_url"] = None
```

I don't want a naked `except` clause because it's bad practice.

Comment: `except (IndexError, KeyError):`? I'd strongly recommend reading [basic tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) before asking.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is this the syntax for `either`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can catch multiple types of errors in one line.

From [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions):

> An except clause may name multiple exceptions as a parenthesized tuple

It would be more pythonic to catch your errors like so:

`except (IndexError, KeyError)...`

Answer (score 2):

You can catch multiple exceptions in a single line;

```
final_dict["short_title"] = article_as_dict["short_title"]
try:
    final_dict["picture_url"] = article_as_dict["main_image"]["img"][-1]["link"]
except (IndexError, KeyError) as e:
    final_dict["picture_url"] = None
```